# Python: Visualise data in line graph and group by category

Tags: python, graph, seaborn, data-visualization, linegraph

I have a CSV file containing data that I would like to visualise in a line graph.

The below is a simplified example of the data.

```
data = {'Day': ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday'],
        '1pm': [2,3,4,5,5,4], 
        '2pm': [5,6,7,5,4,3], 
        '3pm': [1,3,5,7,4,2]}  

  
    Day        1pm  2pm 3pm
0   Monday     2    5   1
1   Tuesday    3    6   3
2   Wednesday  4    7   5
3   Monday     5    5   7
4   Tuesday    5    4   4
5   Wednesday  4    3   2
```

I am trying to set the x-axis as the time and the y-axis as the values. However, I would also like to categorise the results by the day of the week. For example, two lines of the same colour for Monday, two lines of the same colour for Tuesday, and three lines of the same colour for Wednesday (identifiable from a key).The below is an example.

[image: example]

I have been struggling with this and would appreciate some help!

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Try this 2 lines:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('Day').T
df.plot(color={"Monday": "red", "Tuesday": "green",'Wednesday':'blue'}).legend(df.columns.unique())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Although there's a slight issue with the legend. My 'Days' are in a random order e.g. Tuesday, Monday, Wednesday, etc. So when I set the legend, the colours correspond to the order they are presented in my data rather than the colours I allocated to them. Do you have any advice on this?

Comment: I edited the code and make the colors change based on the order of days in the dataframe.